# Defining a color in python

Tags: python, colors

I have a question that may be straight forward, or may be impossible to answer, I'm not sure. I'm wondering how I can define a color in python.

For example, I would like to simply do this:

```
myColor = #920310
```

However, using the '#' sign in python automatically comments anything following.
Is there a way around this? Thank you and sorry if this question is very simple

Comment: How do you intend to use the variable?

Comment: A color in what context? The way you define a color likely depends on what you intend to use it with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want it as a string, do

```
myColor = '#920310'
```

If you actually want it to be a `Color` object, you can do something like

```
myColor = Color('#920310')
```

and interpret it in `Color`'s constructor.

If the question is can you make `#` not be interpreted as a comment, then the answer is no. If `#` wasn't a comment, it wouldn't be Python any more.

You could define your own, Python-like language where a `#` after an `=` wouldn't mean a comment (since that's not valid Python anyway) and it wouldn't break any code, but you wouldn't be able to use the `#` syntax elsewhere without breaking code.

Comment: kudos for the "wouldn't be python any more" part

Comment: The new syntax part was what was interesting, but it wasn't clear what he meant, so I pretty much had to :)

Comment: As for the syntax `Color('#920310')`, you could use [colour python module](http://github.com/vaab/colour) which use this exact same syntax. Disclaimer: I'm the author of this module.

Comment: @vaab I guess you should post an answer here mentioning about `colour`. It seems much better than using a string to denote a color

Answer (score 3):

```
myColor = int('920310', 16) #as an integer (assuming an RGB color in hex)
```

```
myColor = '#920310' #as a string
```

```
from collections import namedtuple
Color = namedtuple("Color", "R G B")
myColor = Color(0x92, 0x03, 0x10)
#as a namedtuple
```

There are lots of things you could be looking for, and equally many ways to use it. Ultimately, it depends on how you want to use this color.

Comment: thank you very much, will start with the simple string solution ^^

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you are planning to use the values, you have many options:

```
colorString = "#920310"
colorList   = [0x93, 0x03, 0x10] 
colorTuple  = (0x93, 0x03, 0x10)
colorDict   = {
   "R" : 0x93,
   "G" : 0x03,
   "B" : 0x10,
}
```

Or, if you're planning to have several operations to deal with your color, say convert to different formats, you can define a Color class:

```
class Color(object):
    def __init__(self, r, g, b):
        self._color = (r,g,b)

    def get_tuple(self):
        return self._color

    def get_str(self):
        return "#%02X%02X%02X" % self._color

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_str()

    def get_YUV(self):
        # ...
```

Example usage:

```
>>> a = Color(0x93, 0x03, 0xAA) # set using hex
>>> print a
#9303AA
>>> b = Color(12, 123, 3) # set using int
>>> print b
#0C7B03
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mycolor = '#<colorcodehere>'
```

mycolor will be seen as a string, so everything inside the apices will be read (# too)